# Grammar Semantics : "May I know the issue that you are facing with your computer ? "

Tags: grammar

I am in tech support and I need to ask the following question to a customer often :

> - "May I know the issue that you are facing with your computer ?"
> - "May I know what issue you are facing with your computer ?"
> - "May I know what kind of issue you are facing with you computer ?"

**I was wondering , which one of these would be the most appropriate ...**

Comment: i am in tech support and i need to ask this question to customer.

Comment: I would just settle for 'Can you please describe the issue'. I'm assuming you both know it's a computer issue.

Comment: internet is not working

Answer (score 3):

How can I help you? What problems are you experiencing?